# Capture Unique Constraint on POST in DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a unique field like so:

**models.py**

```py
class MyModel(...):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, ...)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=32, ...)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields = ['name', 'key'],
                ...
            ),
        ]
```

If I send a POST request where `name` is more than 32 characters, I get back a proper error response:

```json
{"name": ["Ensure this field has no more than 32 characters."]}
```

However, if I send a POST request where the combination of `name` and `key` is not unique, an exception is raised and no message is sent back to the client. How can I capture when a unique constraint is violated and send back a message to the client?

Comment: Use **`serializers.ModelSerializer`** and it will automatically pick the constraints from the model itself.

Comment: This is incorrect - the unique together validation needs to be specified as described in my my answer below.

Comment: hmm, you're right. Seems like there is an option issue [#7173](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7173)

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution, DRF provides `UniqueValidators` [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/):

```py
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        # ToDo items belong to a parent list, and have an ordering defined
        # by the 'position' field. No two items in a given list may share
        # the same position.
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=ToDoItem.objects.all(),
                fields=['list', 'position']
            )
        ]
```